# USB drive @ Startup

Tags: mount, scripts, startup, usb-drive, webserver

Is there a way to check at startup if a USB drive is connected and mounted.
and then launch and application or script.

I want to run a WordPress server, but the website files would be on an external drive.
and I would like that the system checks if drive "X" is connected and mounted.
If it is connected and mounted, then launch (webserver) Wordpress.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way could be that a tool/command called [`findmnt`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/findmnt.8.html) will return `0`(*success*) when the provided argument is a mounted **filesystem** and will return `> 0` otherwise ... Therefore, you can use it in a conditional like this:

```bash
if /bin/findmnt /dev/sda1 > /dev/null 2>&1
  then
    # Do whatever you want when drive is mounted
    echo "mounted"
  else
    # Do whatever you want when drive is not mounted
    echo "not mounted"
  fi
```

**Notice** that `/dev/sda1` is just an example and can be any other device (disk/partition/LV ..etc) identified either directly under `/dev` or by any of these means/paths:

```
$ ls /dev/disk/
by-diskseq  by-id  by-partlabel  by-partuuid  by-path  by-uuid
```

or it can be a mount point like e.g. `/mnt/my_disk` for example.